# Parse JSON HTTP response using golang

Tags: json, go

I am trying to get the value of say "ip" from my following curl output:

```
{  
  "type":"example",
  "data":{  
    "name":"abc",
    "labels":{  
      "key":"value"
    }
  },
  "subsets":[  
    {  
      "addresses":[  
        {  
          "ip":"192.168.103.178"
        }
      ],
      "ports":[  
        {  
          "port":80
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have found many examples in the internet to parse json output of curl requests and I have written the following code, but that doesn't seem to return me the value of say "ip"

```
package main

import (
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"io/ioutil"
"log"
"net/http"
"time"
)

type svc struct {
    Ip string `json:"ip"`
}

func main() {

url := "http://myurl.com"

testClient := http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Second * 2, // Maximum of 2 secs
}

req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}


res, getErr := testClient.Do(req)
if getErr != nil {
    log.Fatal(getErr)
}

body, readErr := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
if readErr != nil {
    log.Fatal(readErr)
}

svc1 := svc{}
jsonErr := json.Unmarshal(body, &svc1)
if jsonErr != nil {
    log.Fatal(jsonErr)
}

fmt.Println(svc1.Ip)
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could provide me hints on what I need to add to my code to get the value of say "ip".

Comment: Your json is not valid., you have one extra `}` right below `ip`, and also commas (`,`) on the last item of two objects (after `80` and after `"192.168.103.178"`). You could use any online json formatter/validator to help you build a valid json - just google it and you will find several options.

Comment: Sorry the extra bracket below `ip` and the extra commas were just a copy & paste fault; the actual curl output is very large so had to shorten it for the sake of this question. I have fixed it in the question now.

Comment: Your `struct` does not match the structure of the JSON input. You're trying to deserialize a large data structure where the `ip` field is deeply nested inside arrays into a single object with a single top-level field that holds a single value - what if there are multiple items in `subsets` or `addresses`? How is it supposed to know that `subsets[n].addresses[m].ip` is supposed to map to `.ip`?

Comment: It also seems like you're confusing the `curl` Linux utility with Go's `http.Client`. They are not at all the same thing.

Comment: @Adrian Yes you are right, there are multiple items under addresses in the actual curl output but what I am interested in is subsets[n].addresses[m].ip that will always map to an IP.

Comment: Right, but that could be multiple entries, which means you need to at some point decode into a slice, not a single value.

Comment: Just a tip, please, do not forget to close body.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create structs which reflect your json structure and then decode your json.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Example struct {
    Type    string   `json:"type,omitempty"`
    Subsets []Subset `json:"subsets,omitempty"`
}

type Subset struct {
    Addresses []Address `json:"addresses,omitempty"`
}

type Address struct {
    IP string `json:"IP,omitempty"`
}

    func main() {

    m := []byte(`{"type":"example","data": {"name": "abc","labels": {"key": "value"}},"subsets": [{"addresses": [{"ip": "192.168.103.178"}],"ports": [{"port": 80}]}]}`)

    r := bytes.NewReader(m)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r)

    val := &Example{}
    err := decoder.Decode(val)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // If you want to read a response body
    // decoder := json.NewDecoder(res.Body)
    // err := decoder.Decode(val)

    // Subsets is a slice so you must loop over it
    for _, s := range val.Subsets {
        // within Subsets, address is also a slice
        // then you can access each IP from type Address
        for _, a := range s.Addresses {
            fmt.Println(a.IP)
        }
    }

}
```

The output would be:
`192.168.103.178`

By decoding this to a struct, you can loop over any slice and not limit yourself to one IP

Example here:

https://play.golang.org/p/sWA9qBWljA

Comment: Thanks for such structured method! However in my case I have json output from a url instead of `m` that you have defined(as shown in my question). In that case, how do I modify the 25th line of your code?

Comment: I'll update my answer to include an example where I read in a response body

Comment: A question- how can one retrieve the ip (i.e 192.168.103.178) from [{[{192.168.103.178}]}]?I tried the strings.Trim function but that complains `cannot use ip (type []Subset) as type string in argument to strings.Trim`

Comment: I've updated the example in the go playground, check that link out

Comment: Yes I had tried that out and that also returns a string of type []Subset (something like `[{[{192.168.103.178}]}]`. Is there a way to extract `192.168.103.178` from the string of type []Subset ?

Comment: The new code @ https://play.golang.org/p/sWA9qBWljA returns exactly `192.168.103.178`, check it out ;)

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering if the for loop could return the value of ip (something like `return a.IP` instead of `fmt.Println(a.IP)`) so that I could use a.IP at other places in my code. Is it possible to achieve that?I am a newbie to golang (have recently switched from Linux ;-) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152294/discussion-between-mike-and-anuribs).

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to unmarshal the JSON to a `map`, e.g. (assumes `jsData` contains JSON string)

```
obj := map[string]interface{}{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsData), &obj); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Next, implement a function for searching the value associated with a key from the map recursively, e.g.

```
func find(obj interface{}, key string) (interface{}, bool) {
    //if the argument is not a map, ignore it
    mobj, ok := obj.(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        return nil, false
    }

    for k, v := range mobj {
        //key match, return value
        if k == key {
            return v, true
        }

        //if the value is a map, search recursively
        if m, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
            if res, ok := find(m, key); ok {
                return res, true
            }
        }
        //if the value is an array, search recursively 
        //from each element
        if va, ok := v.([]interface{}); ok {
            for _, a := range va {
                if res, ok := find(a, key); ok {
                    return res,true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //element not found
    return nil,false
}
```

Note, that the above function return an `interface{}`. You need to convert it to appropriate type, e.g. using type switch:

```
if ip, ok := find(obj, "ip"); ok {
    switch v := ip.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("IP is a string -> %s\n", v)
    case fmt.Stringer:
        fmt.Printf("IP implements stringer interface -> %s\n", v.String())
    case int:

    default:
        fmt.Printf("IP = %v, ok = %v\n", ip, ok)
    }
}
```

A working example can be found at https://play.golang.org/p/O5NUi4J0iR

Answer (score 3):

Typically in these situations you will see people describe all of these sub `struct` types. If you don't actually need to reuse the definition of any sub `struct`s (like as a type for a function argument), then you don't need to define them. You can just use one definition for the whole response. In addition, in some cases you don't need to define a type at all, you can just do it at the time of declaration:

```
package main
import "encoding/json"

const s = `
{  
   "subsets": [
      {  
         "addresses": [ 
            {"ip": "192.168.103.178"}
         ]
      }
   ]
}
`

func main() {
   var svc struct {
      Subsets []struct {
         Addresses []struct { Ip string }
      }
   }
   json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &svc)
   ip := svc.Subsets[0].Addresses[0].Ip
   println(ip == "192.168.103.178")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own decoder or use existing third-party decoders. 
For instance, [github.com/buger/jsonparser](http://github.com/buger/jsonparser) could solve your problem by iterating throw array (two times).

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/buger/jsonparser"
    "fmt"
)

var data =[]byte(`{
  "type":"example",
  "data":{
    "name":"abc",
    "labels":{
      "key":"value"
    }
  },
  "subsets":[
    {
      "addresses":[
        {
          "ip":"192.168.103.178"
        }
      ],
      "ports":[
        {
          "port":80
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`)

func main() {
    jsonparser.ArrayEach(data, func(value []byte, dataType jsonparser.ValueType, offset int, err error) {
        jsonparser.ArrayEach(value, func(value []byte, dataType jsonparser.ValueType, offset int, err error) {
            v, _, _, err := jsonparser.Get(value, "ip")
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            fmt.Println("ip: ", string(v[:]))
        }, "addresses")
    }, "subsets")
}
```

Output: *ip:  192.168.103.178*

Comment: This seems like an unnecessarily heavy-weight solution to a simple data structure mismatch.

Comment: @anuribs data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)